# Sales this month vs last month last year

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have table like this

```
codeCustomer , NameCustomer, Period, Sales
1              AA            201201  12
2              AB            201201  13
1              AA            201101  10
2              AB            201101   9
```

And I would like to compare Period 201201 vs 2011 using SQL Server 2008.

Comment: MYQUERY : SELECT kode_lang,tgldokjdi,
SUM(Case When Month=(left (datename(month, dateadd(month,-11,CAST(tgldokjdi+'01' AS datetime))), 3)) Then 
 sales Else 0 End) LMLY, 
 SUM(Case When Month=(left (DATENAME(MONTH, CAST(tgldokjdi+'01' AS datetime)),3))  Then
sales Else 0 End) CM  
FROM nv..BI_DATA2015_v1 GROUP BY kode_lang,tgldokjdi

Answer (score 0):

Use `SUM` and `GROUP BY` functions.

Query

```
SELECT Period, SUM(Sales) As "Total Sales"
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY Period
```

Output

```
Period  Total Sales
201101  19
201201  25
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/91aa50/2/0

Comment: i want like : ThisMonthSales, LastMonthSales, Period,NameCustomer

Comment: like what? please be more specific in your question

Comment: @YayanMulyana do you mean last month or last year?

Comment: sorry i mean samemonth in last year

Comment: hii @Matt my query in this url, but still error : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31603582/query-for-lastyear-same-month